# How to deselect the selected UIButton when another button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have a code in which I add buttons to scroll view using `for` loop . when I select a button the titlecolor of the button changes due to uicontrolstateselected . when I click the next button , the title color of the previously selected button remains same / retained . How can I get back the normal state of the intially selected button  ?

Comment: Some of the answers is helpful for you? Then why you dons accept one?

Answer (score 1):

create a property prevButton in your interface. write this code in your click method

```
-(void)butonClick:(UIButton *)sender {

    if(prevButton) {
        [prevButton setSelected:NO];
    }     
    prevButton = sender;

    //rest code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
[button setSelected:NO]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hold all of your buttons in an array:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray * buttonContainer;
```

Declare a method in your controller like this:

```
- (void)changeButtonState:(UIButton *)button {

    for (UIButton * button in [self buttonContainer]) {

        [button setSelected:NO];

    }

    [button setSelected:YES];

}
```

And call it in your button action method like this:

```
- (void)someButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self changeButtonState:sender];

    // Rest of your action

}
```

Comment: No need to add the for loop. just keep the track of previously selected button